# What can I do to improve my question about gibbs sampling?

Tags: discussion

So a while back, I ask a question about Gibbs sampling, but got no response.

[If I use Gibbs sampling with a Bayesian model, what do I have to check is memoryless?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/67295/if-i-use-gibbs-sampling-with-a-bayesian-model-what-do-i-have-to-check-is-memory)

My question is really about a particular preprocessing step doing in Bayesian models and better understand the assumptions being made. (So its question about a specific aspect of a data science algorithm)  I hope by improving my question, I can eventually get an answer.